# Recieving message from camel route in java

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

To use my deployed bundle containing camel route as my middleware I want to send message to camel route, which sends to cxf endpoint. The response is logged. Now my external application if i use `MessageConsumer`, is not able to recieve the response from camel route.

Is there a way to get response message from camel route in my main program and print it?

Comment: Can you pls add some more information like, e.g. the routes?

Comment: from("activemq:queue:fork-customers")
    .routeId("activemq:queue:fork-customers")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("freemarker:Envelope.ftl")
    .setHeader("operationName", simple("findCustomer"))
    .to("cxf:bean:my-ws?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
    .to("file://E://Target//Response");

Comment: MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
TextMessage textMessage = session
    .createTextMessage("<root><arg0>AGI00002</arg0></root>");
producer.send(textMessage);
/****** here i want to display my cxf response******/

Comment: finally found issue. The solution is creating a consumer queue, Message and  setting the Message with JMSReplyTo header to the created queue. The response message should be sent to this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my final route. and it receives request from external application, send webservice request to cxf endpoint, receives and sends back response to inonly queue, which is consumed in external application.

```
from("activemq:queue:fork-customers")
                .routeId("activemq:queue:fork-customers")
                .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader((String) exchange.getIn().getBody())));
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(doc);
                    }
                })
                .to("freemarker:Envelope.ftl")
                .setHeader("operationName", simple("findCustomer"))
                .to("cxf:bean:my-webservice?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
                .to("log:reply")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlRouting.class);
                        Message msg = exchange.getIn();
                        log.info("CXF Response : " +msg.toString());                        
                    }
                })
                .to("file://E://Target//Response")
                .inOnly("activemq:queue:jmsResponse");
```

The external application code that produces and send message to activemq and receives the response through an inonly activemq.

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "tcp://localhost:61616");
        // Create a Connection
        String userName = "smx";
        String password = "smx";
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(userName,
                password);
        connection.start();
        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        // Create the destination (Queue)
        Queue destination = session.createQueue("fork-customers");
        // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        // pass the arguements here
        TextMessage textMessage = session
                .createTextMessage("<root><arg0>CUST1001</arg0></root>");
        // Tell the producer to send the message
        Queue tempQueue = session.createQueue("jmsResponse");
        textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
        producer.send(textMessage);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(tempQueue);
        Message response = consumer.receive();
        String text;
        if (response instanceof TextMessage) {
            text = ((TextMessage) response).getText();
        } else {
            byte[] body = new byte[(int) ((BytesMessage) response)
                    .getBodyLength()];
            ((BytesMessage) response).readBytes(body);
            text = new String(body);
        }
        System.out.println("responseMsg " + text);
        // Clean up
        session.close();
        connection.close();
```